# Javascript regex: replace url text link with image,but not in html tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Hi this is my pice of code:

```
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 445px;">[IMG]http://i29.tinypic.com/mydog.png[/IMG] tak si to http://i29.tinypic.com/mycat.png  Lorem ipsum loremai <img width="15" border="0" align="middle" src="images/smejo.gif" valign="middle"/> <img src=http://www.example.com/index.png alt> <img src="http://www.example.com/index.png" alt>     <a href="#reakcia" title="reagovat na temu"><span class="poradna-tl-reaguj"><reaction> </span></a></div>
        </td>           </tr><img src=http://www.example.com/index.png alt><img src="http://www.example.com/index.png" alt>
```

and i need regex pattern to replace ONLY **text image links** with image **without** touch of inner url tags.
But i can't use "*Lookbehind*" or *possessive quantifiers* because JS don't support them=/
So i want to catch only "http://i29.tinypic.com/mydog.png" and "http://i29.tinypic.com/mycat.png".

I using array method to replacing (will be greasemonkey script.)
Many Thanks

Comment: why don't you use a dom parser instead of regex ?

Answer (score 0):

...whole day i cant solved this and now after few minutes...

Answer

```
((?:(?:https?|ftp|file)://|www\.|ftp\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$?!:,.]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|$]+.(jpg|png|gif|jpeg|bmp))(?!([^<]+)?>)
```

Comment: The trailing part of a URL is not necessarily related to the filetype; there is no reason an image resource has to end with .gif/.jpeg/etc.